# Scalebox method returns error while using binom

Tags: scale, scalebox

```
$\scalebox{2}{\binom{2}{3x+3}}$
```

The code works if I use mathlarger, but curious to know why scalebox doesn't work here and what's wrong with my code as I've been working on this for an hour but didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Please add preamble etc. via the Edit button, i.e. code we can copy, run and still see your problem. Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a somewhat strange thing to do, typographically. May I ask what you are trying to achieve by scaling?

Comment: I'm relatively new to the world of LaTeX and I'm trying to make the scaling of the individual formulas somehow suitable for a research paper (either by resizing and or re-scaling). This had been the point I was stuck.

Comment: @user668687 - Instead of scaling up, e.g., by executing `\scalebox{2}{$\binom{2}{3x+3}$}`, you may want to look into using `\displaystyle`, e.g., by running `$\displaystyle\binom{2}{3x+3}$`. Please see my answer for more on this subject.

Comment: for  a paper for publication I would avoid any scaling of text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace

```
$\scalebox{2}{\binom{2}{3x+3}}$
```

with

```
\scalebox{2}{$\binom{2}{3x+3}$}
```

Why? Because the argument of `\scalebox` is in text mode by default, whereas `\binom` needs to be processed in math mode.

[image]

It's not clear to me why one would ever consider embedding a `\binom` expression in a `\scalebox`. If your use case is simply that you need to enlarge the `binom` expresson while in inline math mode, you should definitely not be using `\scalebox{$\binom{2}{3x+3}$}`; instead, do write either `$\displaystyle\binom{2}{3x+3}$` or, more succinctly, `$\dbinom{2}{3x+3}$`. (`\dbinom` and `\tbinom` are to `\binom` as `\dfrac` and `\tfrac` are to `\frac`.)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\begin{document}
$\binom{2}{3x+3}$ vs.\ 
\scalebox{2}{$\binom{2}{3x+3}$}
\qquad
$\displaystyle\binom{2}{3x+3}$ vs.\ 
\scalebox{2}{$\displaystyle\binom{2}{3x+3}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've got the right reason.  It's still not really a good thing to do, though.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I fully agree with you! :-) I hope the OP will notice how much better `$\displaystyle\binom{2}{3x+3}$` looks than `\scalebox{2}{$\binom{2}{3x+3}$}`.

Comment: What about `\dbinom` instead of `\displaystyle\binom`?

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I guess that in my own papers, I occasionally get to choose between `\frac`, `\dfrac`, and `\tfrac`; given the field I'm in, I never get to use `\binom`, let alone `tbinom` and `\dbinom`... I'll post an addendum to mention the existence of `\dbinom` and `\tbinom`.